# Laravel - Unique validation ignore on update not working

Tags: php, laravel

my email unique validation is not working.

From this form, I am sending a `user`

```
<form id="edit-form" class="mt-4" action="{{ route('user.update', 1) }}" method="post">
    @csrf @method('put')
</form>
```

It goes here to my `web.php`

```
Route::prefix('/user')->group(function () {
   Route::put('/update/{user}', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'update'])->name('user.update');
});
```

Then it comes here in the controller

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

Which calls this request form:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'email' => ['nullable', Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($this->id, 'id'), 'email:rfc', 'max:255'],
    ];
}
```

Yet everytime, if I send the same email the model already has, it will say that the email is already in use.

Comment: I've found at least 10 other instances of this question on SO, but no answers yet.

Comment: What if you replace it with just `Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($this->id)`

Comment: @Vivick, same issue occurs.

Comment: Can you `dd($this->id);` just prior to the return statement of the rule please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you use this route definition for your update route:

```php
Route::put('update/{user}', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'update'])->name('user.update');
```

When using the `route` helper, you should pass in an entire user model:

```php
<form id="edit-form" class="mt-4" action="{{ route('user.update', ['user' => $user]) }}" method="post">
    @csrf @method('put')
</form>
```

You should update the `update` method on your `UserController`:

```php
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    //
}
```

In your `UpdateuserRequest` you will now be able to simply do this:

```php
Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($this->user)
```

Comment: It seems that simply changing it from `$this->id` to `$this->user` has done the trick. Thus: `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user)`.

Answer (score 0):

putting here, its not formatting in comment. Its not the actual solution but worked for me inside the controller, try it, if that works it should work in validation request class as well.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => ['nullable', Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($id), 'email:rfc', 'max:255'],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }

        return response('updated');
    }
```